# linq like empty string

Tags: linq, sql-like, contains

```
var list = (from i in _dataContext.aspnet_Users.Include("aspnet_Membership")  where i.UserName.Contains(userName)  select i ).ToList();
```

if `userName=""` then nothing return. how can i do that if empty string then return all records?

Comment: Please clarify, I don't have a clue what you're asking. - Edit - on second thought, I think I've got it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do:

```
  var list = 
      (from i in _dataContext.aspnet_Users.Include("aspnet_Membership") 
        where string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)
               || i.UserName.Contains(userName)  
       select i ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Fun Fact: The System.Data.Linq.SqlClient namespace includes a few helper methods that are pretty useful.

You can use the SqlMethods.Like function which will return all results if an empty string is passed to it.

Ex:

```
 (from i in _dataContext.aspnet_Users.Include("aspnet_Membership") 
  where SqlMethods.Like(i.UserName, "%" + userName + "%")
  select i).ToList();
```

Comment: Nix: You're right, I assumed too quickly. Fun fact still stands though ;)